# postgres vs mysql with regard to group by

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have two tables `albums` and `bands`, and I want to see which albums don't have bands. I use the following Mysql query and it works fine:

```
select bands.name from bands 
left join albums on bands.id = albums.band_id 
group by albums.band_id 
having count(albums.id) = 0;
```

But in Postgresql, I get the following error:

```
Query 1: ERROR:  column "bands.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function 
LINE 4: select bands.name from bands left join albums on bands.id = ...
```

Why is that? I feel like postgres is more sql compliant, no?

Comment: Yes, that's a bug in MySQL

Comment: Unrelated, but: I personally would use a NOT EXISTS condition instead (which removes the need for a group by completely)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that s what I did indeed.

Comment: Because accepting such an invalid group by and returning random results is a bug, not a feature. This is indeed fixed by the introduction/enabling of only_full_group_by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I use the following Mysql query and it works fine:

It works fine because it depends on the sql_mode only_full_group_by which is disabled.

Enable it first by checking the sql_mode ,

```
mysql> select @@sql_mode;
+------------------------+
| @@sql_mode             |
+------------------------+
| NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Enable it by ,

```
 set global sql_mode ='NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';
```

You should add it on the .cnf file as well under the `[mysqld]`

```
[mysqld]

sql-mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY"
```